# Execution failed for task ':image_picker:compileDebugJavaWithJavac' in flutter

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, flutter-dependencies

I don't know what's wrong with my Flutter, am getting this error:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on NOTE 5 in debug mode...
Initializing gradle...                                             20.2s
Resolving dependencies...                                         149.7s (!)
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Note: C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\cloud_firestore-0.12.11\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\cloudfirestore\CloudFirestorePlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.

Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

Note: C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\cloud_firestore-0.12.11\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\cloudfirestore\CloudFirestorePlugin.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.

Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\image_picker-0.4.12+1\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\imagepicker\ImagePickerDelegate.java:15: error: package android.support.annotation does not exist

import android.support.annotation.VisibleForTesting;

                                 ^

C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\image_picker-0.4.12+1\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\imagepicker\ImagePickerDelegate.java:16: error: cannot find symbol

import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;

                             ^

  symbol:   class ActivityCompat

  location: package android.support.v4.app

C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\image_picker-0.4.12+1\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\imagepicker\ImagePickerDelegate.java:17: error: package android.support.v4.content does not exist

import android.support.v4.content.FileProvider;

                                 ^

C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\image_picker-0.4.12+1\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\imagepicker\ImagePickerFileProvider.java:3: error: package android.support.v4.content does not exist

import android.support.v4.content.FileProvider;

                                 ^

C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\image_picker-0.4.12+1\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\imagepicker\ImagePickerFileProvider.java:10: error: cannot find symbol

public class ImagePickerFileProvider extends FileProvider {}

                                             ^

  symbol: class FileProvider

C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\image_picker-0.4.12+1\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\imagepicker\ImagePickerPlugin.java:8: error: package android.support.annotation does not exist

import android.support.annotation.VisibleForTesting;

                                 ^

C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\image_picker-0.4.12+1\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\imagepicker\ImagePickerDelegate.java:68: error: cannot find symbol

  @VisibleForTesting static final int REQUEST_CODE_CHOOSE_IMAGE_FROM_GALLERY = 2342;

   ^

  symbol:   class VisibleForTesting

  location: class ImagePickerDelegate

C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\image_picker-0.4.12+1\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\imagepicker\ImagePickerDelegate.java:69: error: cannot find symbol

  @VisibleForTesting static final int REQUEST_CODE_TAKE_IMAGE_WITH_CAMERA = 2343;

   ^

  symbol:   class VisibleForTesting

  location: class ImagePickerDelegate

C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\image_picker-0.4.12+1\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\imagepicker\ImagePickerDelegate.java:70: error: cannot find symbol

  @VisibleForTesting static final int REQUEST_EXTERNAL_IMAGE_STORAGE_PERMISSION = 2344;

   ^

  symbol:   class VisibleForTesting

  location: class ImagePickerDelegate

C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\image_picker-0.4.12+1\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\imagepicker\ImagePickerDelegate.java:71: error: cannot find symbol

  @VisibleForTesting static final int REQUEST_CAMERA_IMAGE_PERMISSION = 2345;

   ^

  symbol:   class VisibleForTesting

  location: class ImagePickerDelegate

C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\image_picker-0.4.12+1\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\imagepicker\ImagePickerDelegate.java:72: error: cannot find symbol

  @VisibleForTesting static final int REQUEST_CODE_CHOOSE_VIDEO_FROM_GALLERY = 2352;

   ^

  symbol:   class VisibleForTesting

  location: class ImagePickerDelegate

C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\image_picker-0.4.12+1\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\imagepicker\ImagePickerDelegate.java:73: error: cannot find symbol

  @VisibleForTesting static final int REQUEST_CODE_TAKE_VIDEO_WITH_CAMERA = 2353;

   ^

  symbol:   class VisibleForTesting

  location: class ImagePickerDelegate

C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\image_picker-0.4.12+1\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\imagepicker\ImagePickerDelegate.java:74: error: cannot find symbol

  @VisibleForTesting static final int REQUEST_EXTERNAL_VIDEO_STORAGE_PERMISSION = 2354;

   ^

  symbol:   class VisibleForTesting

  location: class ImagePickerDelegate

C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\image_picker-0.4.12+1\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\imagepicker\ImagePickerDelegate.java:75: error: cannot find symbol

  @VisibleForTesting static final int REQUEST_CAMERA_VIDEO_PERMISSION = 2355;

   ^

  symbol:   class VisibleForTesting

  location: class ImagePickerDelegate

C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\image_picker-0.4.12+1\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\imagepicker\ImagePickerDelegate.java:77: error: cannot find symbol

  @VisibleForTesting final String fileProviderName;

   ^

  symbol:   class VisibleForTesting

  location: class ImagePickerDelegate

C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\image_picker-0.4.12+1\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\imagepicker\ImagePickerDelegate.java:164: error: cannot find symbol

  @VisibleForTesting

   ^

  symbol:   class VisibleForTesting

  location: class ImagePickerDelegate

C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\image_picker-0.4.12+1\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\imagepicker\ImagePickerPlugin.java:40: error: cannot find symbol

  @VisibleForTesting

   ^

  symbol:   class VisibleForTesting

  location: class ImagePickerPlugin

C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\image_picker-0.4.12+1\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\imagepicker\ImagePickerDelegate.java:122: error: cannot find symbol

            return ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, permissionName)

                   ^

  symbol: variable ActivityCompat

C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\image_picker-0.4.12+1\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\imagepicker\ImagePickerDelegate.java:128: error: cannot find symbol

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, new String[] {permissionName}, requestCode);

            ^

  symbol: variable ActivityCompat

C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\image_picker-0.4.12+1\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\imagepicker\ImagePickerDelegate.java:140: error: cannot find symbol

            return FileProvider.getUriForFile(activity, fileProviderName, file);

                   ^

  symbol: variable FileProvider

20 errors



FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.



* What went wrong:

Execution failed for task ':image_picker:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.



* Try:

Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.



* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org



BUILD FAILED in 4m 35s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                            287.0s (!)
*******************************************************************************************
The Gradle failure may have been because of AndroidX incompatibilities in this Flutter app.
See for more information on the problem and how to fix it.
*******************************************************************************************
Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 3):

It worked for me by changing the image_picker version to image_picker: ^0.6.0+9

Answer (score 0):

As the last error says:

`The Gradle failure may have been because of AndroidX incompatibilities in this Flutter app. See for more information on the problem and how to fix it.`

You need to migrate your Android module to AndroidX. Most of the flutter dependencies now built with AndroidX, so you better to upgrade your project too.

In Android Studio or IntelliJ, you can migrate by accessing menu Refactor -> Migrate to AndroidX...

Comment: After i opened my project, android module in android studio, I clicked on refactor, migrate to androidX, I got this error: No usages found in the project, what's wrong?

Comment: you need to migrate manually. see flutter documentation for that.